# Tkinter disable Return key behaviour on function call

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to print the widget contents after pressing `Control+Return`, but after I press it, it adds a new line. How do I disable the Enter key behaviour when calling the function?

```
from Tkinter import *

def test(event):
    a1 = e.get(1.0, END)
    print a1

root = Tk()
e = Text(root)
e.pack()
root.bind('<Control-Return>', test)
root.mainloop()
```

`return 'break'` doesn't do what I want, as I saw in other questions.

I could get the cursor position and delete the new line created, but I think there's a better way.

*Python 2.7*

Comment: `root.bind('<Control-space>', test)`  doesn't add a space... possible workaround

Comment: Oh, that's weird.. It seems I cannot use `Return` when binding text widgets then

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I was binding to `root`, if I bind it to the text widget itself and add `return 'break'`, it works as intended.

```
from Tkinter import *

def test(event):
    a1 = e.get(1.0, END)
    print a1
    return 'break'

root = Tk()
e = Text(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Control-Return>', test)
root.mainloop()
```